Rest API with ADF
Could you advise what is the best solution to use with azure data factory to connect to an API rest, i found some methos to be used as request for the API with XML, C#... in order to get the token, oahtorization.
What is the best way to do it using activity web in adf? and how we can convert the response to a parquet file in the blob storage.
Thank you.

You can use copy activity to achieve your requirement.
First, use a web activity to get the required bearer token. You can follow this approach for the bearer token.
Create REST linked service and dataset. After getting the bearer token, use copy activity with your REST API as source dataset.
In the headers, give the bearer token from the previous web activity like below.
Bearer @{activity('<web_activity_name>').output.access_token}


Create parquet dataset and give your desired name for it. This parquet file will be generated after the pipeline run.

Give this dataset as a sink of the copy activity.

Now, run the pipeline and the required parquet file will be generated in the target location.

Thanks for your comment but the request for API we have to use xml as request not autorisation with bareer

And the response just to get token is an xml too or c# and we need to extract from it the token

If there is a need for executing C# code, you should use a custom activity to run your code and get the bearer token from this activity. After that, follow the above process using copy activity.

You can use Web activity in ADF to retrieve the Outh2 Access token using Post method and configuring the URL and header correctly:

For complete implementation you can go through this blog post by Balamurugan Balakreshnan
The response from the API is typically in JSON format , to convert it to parquet file, you could use copy activity and save the response in parquet format in Blob storage/ ADLS as sink in copy activity.
